# jQuery if input[type="radio"] before clickable label hasn't attribute "checked" then do NOT add it, else do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help me to implement this behavior.
I would like to check if after click on a label next to radiobutton this radiobutton already has attribute "checked" then it's ok, let's stay in this stage. But if this element hasn't this attribute, then i won't add it.
This is what i gave birth:

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function (name) {
    return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
};
var lab = $(".rating input[type='radio'] + label");
lab.click(function {
    if ($(this).lab.prev('input').hasAttr('checked')) {
        alert("OK");
    };
});
```

[This is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxdonetsk/25d3bja7/1/)

Please help me guys. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you realize that `$(this)` is the window in your code and not a label? I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing happened.

Comment: You do not have any click code to detect when it changes. That code only runs when the page is loaded. Not going to help you meet your goal until you listen for the change events.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, man, im so disattentive sometimes.

Comment: And there is no `.lab` in jQuery

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.  What do you mean "then I won't add it"?  Add what?  To what?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  To alert OK if the clicked radio is checked?

Comment: If radio before clicked label is checked, than don't delete attribute checked. Else don't add atribute checked. It's like readonly for inputs.

Comment: So your goal is to create a set of radio buttons that cannot be changed after the page loads?  In that case @epascarello has the simplest solution -- disable the radio buttons.

Comment: @max is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/25d3bja7/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ret_info_srars1 label').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).prev('input[type=radio]').is(':checked'))
        alert("OK!");
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/25d3bja7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to figure out whether a radio button is checked in jQuery is:

```
$("input:radio").is(':checked')
```

There is also the change event for radio buttons that you can use:

```
$('.rating input:radio').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert ("changed and checked");
    }
});
```

See it working in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n2jy99wj/)

To set a radio button to be checked use `.prop`

```
$("input:radio").prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but i would like to click on a label after input and check, if this input is not checked than do not apply attribute checked.

Comment: Well then change the event that you're listening for. `$("label").click()` as you have above but the point is that you can use `is(':checked')`. I have updated my answer to tell you how to manually change the value.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just write:

```
$(lab).is(':checked')
{
alert("Radio Button Checked");
}
```

as lab has already been assign with the desired ID.

OR

```
if($("#RadioButtonID).is(':checked'))
{
alert("Radio Button Checked");
}
else
{
alert ("Not Checked");
}
```

Comment: var lab = $(".rating input[type='radio'] + label"); so, label can not to be checked :)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is truly to create a "read-only" set of radio buttons as you indicated in the comments above, the simplest solution is to disable the radio buttons:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/25d3bja7/3/

Comment: I know man, but in the markup i created, I used the property display:none for radiobuttons, and they are already rendered with disabled attribute in DOM. But labels after these inputs are clickable and these inputs are changing attribute checked.

Comment: @max Then you should update your jsFiddle to show your actual markup & css.  It shouldn't make any difference whether display:none is used -- if the radio buttons are disabled, clicking the label will not add the checked property.

By the way, "checked" is a property, not an attribute.